Why does turning on a switch effect the return wire?
So I have an old school bathroom with two switches going to the Fan/Light and Light. I went and bought a new Fan/Light and it has all this new stuff like it's own switch with a red/white/black lines.
It says it wants the black line to go to the hot wire, the red line to go to light and the neutral wire to go to the neutral.
I don't technically have a neutral wire. So instead I hooked up to the switch line of the second switch. This works because this routes through the vanity light and connects to the nuetral wires anyway.
However, this only works as long as I don't turn on the right switch. If I do turn on the right switch, the left box disables it's buttons, and still turns on the vanity light.
I am confused. Why would turning on the vanity light cause the switch line from behaving like a neutral wire.
If I ran a 14/3 up to the junction box, so that I had a neutral wire now, isn't  that new wire just hooking up to the same wires as before...
Is it the fact that we are passing through the vanity light bulb first that the nuetral wire no longer functions correctly?


the neutral is not switched

You have enough wires installed to make it work but not enough to comply with the NEC. Do you have access to run a new wire from the junction box to the switch box? You must either add a new 14/2 or replace one of the existing 14/2 with a 14/3.

You must also read a textbook on residential power circuits. Right now you are just banging stuff together to see if it works. You should not use your house wiring as an experimental lab, as you may discover something that will make you homeless.

When you say I have enough. Are you saying to drop the vanity switch and tie the lights together to one switch? Yes that would work, but I was hoping I wouldnt have to do that, I was also hoping to not have to run another line.

I guess I dont understand the physics. Why would the vanity bulb being on? Effect the ability for other switch to use the line as a neutral. Like in my head a hot wire has like 100 watts on it. Vanity uses like 15 watts. If you tie into the neutral after the vanity light, doesnt your neutral wire still have like 80 watts on it....

The underlying question is about neutral wire behavior, as stated in the comments...

a hot wire has like 100 watts on it. Vanity uses like 15 watts. If you tie into the neutral after the vanity light, doesnt your neutral wire still have like 80 watts on it

Let's go back to where the system neutral gets bonded to the system ground at the main panel.  At this point, we have a reference voltage of zero.  This part of the system is not supplying power or wattage.  It is supplying a zero voltage point.
As the branch circuit wiring routes the many neutral wires throughout the residence, these wires distribute the zero voltage point to the loads.  It's important to understand any resistance represents a load.  That includes the vanity light, damaged wiring, or any human being who happens to be in the path or paths of a neutral wire.
The implication here is that a light bulb with two wires attached should have a neutral wire and a hot wire.  The hot wire is connected in parallel with other loads, and the neutral wire is connected in parallel with other loads.  This also means neutral voltage does not pass through a load and there is no such thing as a "tie into the neutral after the vanity light."  Everything opposite the neutral wire of the load is high voltage.
Attempting to treat a hot wire as neutral will only lead to confusion.  There's also a rabbit hole of non-ohmic loading such as tungsten filaments and LEDs.  This means the load itself doesn't have a constant resistance.
The other point of confusion is the switched hot wire.  When that wire is switched on, it is strictly a hot wire.  It is providing high voltage to the vanity light and there is no interpretation where some other capacity or channel exists for low voltage or neutral current of the same phase and frequency.  In other words, there can't be two different potentials on the same wire.
When the hot wire is switched off, it is NOT a neutral wire.  It is simply a disconnected hot wire.

When the right switch is off, you are powering the circuitry in the new switch by running a trickle current through the lower light, which is not otherwise powered. Apparently that's letting enough current through to run the switch's electronics.
If the right switch is on, you now have the new switch's power and neutral connections both at 120 volts, or close enough to that. That zero volt differential is not going to allow that trickle current, so the electronics in the new switch get no power and can't operate.
If all the switches are in the same box, you could fix this electrically by reassigning one of the two unswitched hot wires to be a neutral, making very sure that these are labelled/colored correctly so it's clear which is which since otherwise there is severe risk of short circuit. But my impression is that even if marked appropriately this would not meet code requirements. Pros: please confirm or correct me on this.
(Personally I consider switch loops Evil. I understand why they were popular in some styles of construction, but ugh.)

Switch loops are evil today. Once upon a time they were the bee's knees.

More about that trickle thing. Why does it stop working when the right switch is turned on? I guess I don't understand the physics. If I run a nuetral wire up and tie in after the vanity light, wouldn't it recieve just as much of a signal when the vanity is turned on? Like I don't understand why the light blub in the middle would make that much of a difference.

@BobbyOcean: Second paragraph. But I'll try to expand on it.

Maybe it is the the smart switches that are evil. Making you rip out perfectly good circuits just so they can work.

@RobertChapin: Disagree. The problem is specifically that the new controller needs a neutral in addition to the hot and switched-hot, and the current attempt to kludge past that doesn't work.

@crip659: Well, it would help if more smart hyphen switches were designed and certified to be able to sink the tiny amount of power they need to ground. I am deliberately not suggesting that, of course, though I have to admit I would be tempted in this situation.

@keshlam We can agree about the kludge and the overall need for a proper solution.  Perhaps my comment was unclear.

Sigh. I have got  to stop trusting voice transcription.... Yeah, we agree that the issue here is incompatible assumptions in the hardware..

Thanks @keshlam, you were probably saying the same thing as Robert Chapin, he just came out slightly more clear for my incompetence. I will be running a new 14/3 wire, that seems the only logical way to finish this bathroom.
